# Performance output of a filter condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know if the position of a particular filter-condition within a query would result in significant performance difference.

I have a sample table - `date_dim`: Which will always hold only 1 record pertaining to the current date of execution:

```
dt | frst_day_mth | last_day_mth
16/05/2019 | 01/05/2019 | 31/05/2019  -- Table always has only 1 row for that day
```

Now I have a query like:

```
select a.id, b.name, c.salary
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
on a.id = b.id
inner join tableC c
on b.name = c.name
```

Now, I have to apply a date filter condition on such as `tableA.eff_dt <= date_dim.last_mth_day`.
My question is - which Option (below) would be the best from a performance perspective ? Is it better to put it in the `ON clause` in the `Join` (Option 1) with a `subquery` so that the records could get reduced early, or apply it later in a `where` clause (Option 2) ? The tables A, B & C has about 20 Mil rows each. I am using Spark SQL.

Option 1:

```
select a.id, b.name, c.salary
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
on a.id = b.id
and a.eff_dt <= (select last_mth_day from date_dim) -- Using subquery early on
inner join tableC c
on b.name = c.name
```

Option 2:

```
select a.id, b.name, c.salary
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
on a.id = b.id
inner join tableC c
on b.name = c.name
cross join date_dim dt 
where a.eff_dt <= dt.last_mth_day -- Using Later in WHERE clause
```

Please let me know your comments.

Comment: Test it on your data and let us know what you find.

Comment: look at the explains

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I applied both the Options on my data and I got very negligible difference in query execution times (approx 10 secs), with Option 1 taking the lesser time. The data volume was approx 125 Mil

Answer (score 0):

As the query you have is like filter rows from the table - tableA based on the only value in table - date_dim.

So i believe, where ever you keep the filter the spark query optimizer only read the rows from tableA which are matching with filter condition(this happens because of pushdown filter mechanism). So only those rows participate in the join.

you can refer this link for more information:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Optimizer-PushDownPredicate.html